# Как заменить первую цифру на 7

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных

Подскажите, как заменить первую цифру на 7.

```
   Телефон
   84956895325
   84951491991
   89037481292
   79269431224
```

Comment: На каждый чих будешь вопрос создавать? Попробуй воспользоваться поиском, ты не первый, кто решает такую элементарную задачу.

Comment: Не нашел ответ.

Comment: Не нашел потому что не искал, видимо.

Comment: Ну ты и не разу и не отвечал. Че тебе беспокоиться? Не можешь помочь начинающему? Не помогай.

Comment: Хоть и ответили но добавлю код text = 'abcdefg'   
    text = text[:0] + '7' + text[1:]   
    print(text)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь срезами через [Series.str[]](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html):

```
df["Телефон"] = "7" + df["Телефон"].str[1:]
```

результат:

```
In [206]: df
Out[206]:
       Телефон
0  74956895325
1  74951491991
2  79037481292
3  79269431224
```